# Derivative polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable  function. Assume that
for every $x \in \mathbb R$, there exists an  $n_x\in \mathbb N$, such that $\,f^{(n_x)}(x)=0$. Prove that  $f$ is polynomial.

Comment: I don't understand : what you talk about, what F,f are, what your question is and what you did so far. Please make yourself clear and show your work.

Comment: Try Baire category on {$x: 0=f^{n}(x)=f^{n+1}(x)=....$} to show there is an open set where $f^{k}(x)=0$ for fixed $k$. Then contradiction.

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

Comment: Integrate $n_x$ times? Continuity is guaranteed since $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Did you just find some list of extremely tough problems?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232665/baire-show-that-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-a-polynomial-in-an-open-bo) is almost the same problem, here at MSE.

Comment: Problems like this one are better approached in one knows what their background is: ideas , insights, part of other problems...not to mention to add some self work.

Comment: Type of, these problems I collected during this month

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely correct if we assume that the function $f$ is real analytic. In such case $f$ extends holomorphically in an open neighbourhood $\Omega$ of the real line, so we can imagine $f$ as a holomorphic function in $\Omega$, with $\mathbb R\subset \Omega$.
Let $S_n=\{x\in\mathbb R: f^{(n)}(x)=0 \}$. Then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} S_n=\mathbb R$. Clearly at least one of the $S_n$'s is uncountable, and thus it has an accumulation point $x_0$. That means, that the zero's of $f^{(n)}$ have an accumulation point, which implies that $f^{(n)}$ is identically zero, and thus $f$ a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$.

In the $C^\infty$ case now, I have not produced a proof yet, but this is as much as I could get.
As the $S_n$'s are closed, Baire's Theorem implies the existence of set $S_n$ with nonempty interior. Thus there exists an interval $(a,b)$ where $f^{(n)}$ vanishes and thus $f|_{(a,b)}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$, and clearly the are such interval (for different values of $n$) dense in the whole real line.