# If the $100$-th derivative of $f$ vanishes on $\Bbb R$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I have the following statement:

> If $f^{100}(x) = 0$ for every real number $x$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

I couldn't find a counter example so I would like to get some help for prove/disprove.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $x$ any real number?

Comment: This is only true if the function is defined on a non-empty interval.

Comment: Yes it is a real number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\forall x \,\exists k$ s.t. $f^{(k)}(x)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876319/forall-x-exists-k-s-t-fkx-0-then-f-is-a-polynomial)

Comment: What if the degree of polynomial is $101$

Comment: @gebruiker: Not at all a duplicate!! The other one is a much stronger claim. This one is trivial because every polynomial (including the zero polynomial) has a polynomial anti-derivative.

Comment: Consider the differential equation $f^{(100)}(x) = 0$; integrate once to get $f^{(99)}(x) = c_1$. Repeat and get $f^{(98)}(x) = c_1x+c_2$. ... and continue

Comment: and why the integral is defined ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on taste and preference:

1. 0 is a polynomial. Integrate it, and you get a polynomial of degree $\le{0}$. Integrate that, and you get a polynomial of degree $\le{1}$. Integrate 100 times and you have $f(X)$ as a polynomial of degree $\le{99}$.
2. More formally, try a proof by induction. Prove that if the proposition is true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$, then note that it is true if you differentiate $f(x)$ $n=0$ times.