# For every $x \in [a,b] , \exists n_x\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $f^{(n_x) }(x)=0$ ; then to prove $f$ is a polynomial in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces, continuity, baire-category

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous  function having derivatives of all order such that for every $x \in [a,b] , \exists n_x\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $f^{(n_x) }(x)=0$ ; then how do I show that $f$ is a polynomial in $[a,b]$ ?

My try : For every $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ define $E_n:=\{x\in[a,b]:f^{(n)}(x)=0\}$ , so each $E_n$ is closed and by given condition , $[a,b]=\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ , since $[a,b]$ is compact it is complete and also it is not hollow ( has non-empty interior) , so by Baire's category theorem , at least one of $E_n$ has non-empty interior , so for some $k\in \mathbb Z^+$ , $E_k$ contains an open ball $B(y,r)$ where $y \in [a,b]$ and then $f^{(k)}(x)=0 , \forall x \in B(y,r)  $ and then I am stuck , please help .

I would also like to ask ; Can the proposition be proved without Baire's theorem ?

Comment: [This post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) has some information.

Comment: @David mitra : I don't understand what is $X = \{x: \forall (a,b)\ni x: f\restriction_{(a,b)}\text{ is not a polynomial} \}$ ?

Comment: The set of $x$ such that $f$ is not a polynomial on any open interval containing $x$.

Comment: @David Mitra: then how is $X$ closed ?

Comment: Since it's complement is obviously open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Baire: Show that $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial in an open bounded set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232665/baire-show-that-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-a-polynomial-in-an-open-bo)