# Must a closed subset of $R$ with empty interior consist only of isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ is closed and $int(A)=\emptyset$. Can $A$ have any accumulation points? If it can, what criterion must be added for the claim to hold?

This question arose, when I was trying to prove that if $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R^R})$ and $\forall{x\in\mathbb{R}}\exists{n\in\mathbb{N}}\colon f^{(n)}(x)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial. The set I am trying to prove to consist of only isolated points is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}| \forall (a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}\colon (x\in (a,b) \implies f|_{(a,b)} $ is not a polynomial$)\}$.

Comment: What about the Cantor set?

Comment: or how about {1,1/2,1/3, ...} U {0}?

Comment: Unfortunately they both seem to work. That's too bad. Thank you for the example nonetheless.

Comment: The general mindset is that open sets are quite easy to understand and closed sets are horribly complicated.

Comment: Do you want a hint to prove that $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Sure. So far, I have shown that this set is closed and used Baire category theorem to show that this set has empty interior. I know how to prove that it cannot have any isolated points, all I have to deal with now are accumulation points with which I am stuck so far

Comment: Related to your original problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232665/baire-show-that-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-a-polynomial-in-an-open-bo/232691#232691